# Creating SQL Server tables dynamically based on a condition

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following query that will create tables based on year and quarter of a date column. It would run from 2000 till the current year.

In the next run I want the script to create tables only from the latest quarter for the current year. So assuming for this year the table for quarter 4 is already created, I wouldn't want my script to create the table again.

It should only create tables for the new quarters.

```
declare @startyear int = 2000
declare @startQuarter int = 1
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @tableName varchar(50)

while @startYear < year(getdate())
begin
    set @startQuarter = 1

    while @startQuarter < 5
    begin
        set @tableName = 'FinData' + cast (@startYear as varchar) + '_' + cast(@startQuarter as varchar);
        set @sql = '
            drop table [dbo].[' + @tableName + '];
            create table [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] ( calendarYear int, calendarQuarter int, companyid bigint not null, dataitemid bigint not null, dataitemvalue numeric(28,6), fiscalyear int, fiscalquarter int, periodenddate datetime, filingdate datetime, latestforfinancialperiodflag bit, latestfilingforinstanceflag bit );
            insert into [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] select calendarYear, calendarQuarter, companyid, dataitemid, dataitemvalue, fiscalyear, fiscalquarter, periodenddate, filingdate, latestforfinancialperiodflag, latestfilingforinstanceflag
            from openquery([gbips-i-db48d\sql2008r2],''select fp.calendarYear, fp.calendarQuarter, fp.companyid, fd.dataitemid, fd.dataitemvalue, fp.fiscalyear, fp.fiscalquarter, fi.periodenddate, fi.filingdate, fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag, fi.latestfilingforinstanceflag
              from [Xpressfeed_dev].dbo.ciqFinPeriod fp
              inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].dbo.ciqFinInstance fi on fi.financialPeriodId = fp.financialPeriodId
              inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].dbo.ciqFinInstanceToCollection fc on fc.financialInstanceId = fi.financialInstanceId
              inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].dbo.ciqFinCollection c on c.financialCollectionId = fc.financialCollectionId
              inner join [Xpressfeed_dev].dbo.ciqFinCollectionData fd on fd.financialCollectionId = c.financialCollectionId
              where YEAR(fi.periodenddate) = '+ cast(@startYear as varchar) +' and  DATEPART( quarter,fi.periodenddate)  = ' + cast(@startQuarter as varchar ) + ''')'  
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql 

        set @startQuarter += 1
    end

    set @startYear += 1;
end
```

For e.g tables created will be

```
    FinData2017_1
    FinData2017_2
    FinData2017_3
    FinData2017_4
```

Please note that I am using `periodEndDate` to determine the year and quarter and not current system year.

I am running the above script via SSIS job. I want to create table based on a condition. The query below is the condition that i want to check before executing

```
select max(year(periodEndDate)) as Year from ciqFinInstance
select max(Datepart(quarter, periodEndDate)) as Quarter from ciqFinInstance
```

So the tables would be created checking the values in this column. What is the best way to handle this? I would need to loop to run the script from year 2000 to the current year to insert the records as there would be new historical records added on each run but the create table shouldn't be part of this loop.

Comment: I would try to avoid naming tables like this. Instead there should be a column to indicate which period the data belongs in.

Comment: Hi Sean, there is no column. Consider periodenddate as the column to determine the year and quarter

Comment: I think you are missing my point. If you create tables like this you are forced to use dynamic sql for the life of the system because you have will constantly have to figure out which table to select data from. This is a nightmare.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Add another column or columns to your table to hold this information. For example, add FinancialYear as a column and insert the appropriate data. Or add CalendarYear as a column.

Comment: The reasoning behind creating multiple tables and not single tables is faster retrieval of records as you would query only for particular subset year or quarter which would be only subset of the entire records. We had considered partioning and having a single table but some reason that proved costly in terms of storage space it took. Thats out of debate with regards this post.
Consider we need to maintain 4 tables every year that is  4 quarters hence 4 tables how is your suggestion helping

Comment: OK consider the design choice set in stone then. Are you familiar with sys.objects? You would figure out the name of the table you want to create and only create it if it is not already in sys.objects. But honestly doing this in a loop seems crazy. The table will be created the first time, why continue looping every time you run this thing? Why not simply create the tables you need initially. And then at the beginning of each new year add the next set of tables.

Comment: Currently I am in development phase and would need to deploy my script to QA and other environments. Are you saying to maintain two deployments. The first deployment would run the script above and do the initial job. It could just manual execution of storedproc and then second deployment would be SSIS package that would  script will contain only insertion of records and not creation . The ssis package could contain an execute sql task to check sys objects and create table accordingly. But even to do that I would need to check what is current year and quarter right. Please could throw ideas

Comment: Why don't you just create a deployment script that has the tables in it? Why go to all the trouble of making this type of thing 100% dynamic so that it can run one time? Create your tables in your development environment and maintain a deployment script.

Comment: That makes sense. So if i create script for only table, it will create only until 2018 as its quarter 4 of 2017. How do I handle creation of table next year onwards ? I would suppose , I would need to determine the current year and quarter and then check if that exist in sys objects. Where will this additional logic of determining new tables reside ?

Comment: You could just keep a script around to generate one year of tables and execute it as part of your year end process. That script would check sys.objects or sys.tables for the existence of the new table. If it doesn't exist, create the table. that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does makes sense