# value as string in dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server

I am creating dynamic sql and have the following query

```
set @sql = '
             IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo'' AND  TABLE_NAME =' + @tableName +'))
             BEGIN
             create table [dbo].[' + @tableName + '] ( calendarYear int, calendarQuarter int, companyid bigint not null, dataitemid bigint not null, dataitemvalue numeric(28,6), fiscalyear int, fiscalquarter int, periodenddate datetime, filingdate datetime, latestforfinancialperiodflag bit, latestfilingforinstanceflag bit ); 
             END'
            PRINT  @sql
```

Output if the print statement is

```
 IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND  TABLE_NAME =FinData2000_1))
         BEGIN
         create table [dbo].[FinData2000_1] ( calendarYear int, calendarQuarter int, companyid bigint not null, dataitemid bigint not null, dataitemvalue numeric(28,6), fiscalyear int, fiscalquarter int, periodenddate datetime, filingdate datetime, latestforfinancialperiodflag bit, latestfilingforinstanceflag bit ); 
         END
```

I am looking having the condition of the table_name condition in string

For e.g

```
AND  TABLE_NAME = 'FinData2000_1'
```

How do I achieve that in initial dynamic query

Comment: Here we go again....this is still a poor design choice like it was last week when you asked nearly the same question. Or at least the same basic premise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206781/creating-sql-server-tables-dynamically-based-on-a-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a couple of apostrophes inside your string, surrounding the table name. To do this, double up the apostrophes so that instead of being interpreted as "end of string" they are interpreted as "apostrophe character":

```
set @textWithApostrophes = 'it''s ten o''clock'
```

Hence

```
@sql = '... and table_name = ''' + @tablename + ''' blah blah rest of query here'
                             ^^                  ^^
```

I put carets ^^ under everything that "becomes an apostrophe inside an sql string", the other apostrophes are "start or end of a string"